# Hide select tag with just one option tag with css

Tags: php, html, css

My select tag will be auto generated with php. It might happen that there will be just a single option tag inside this select tag.

I tought about using php to check whether there are multiple options or just a single one. If there is just a single one I print a hidden input tag otherwise I'll generate the select option tag.

Is there a css solution to hide a select tag with a single option child or do I have to use my php-solution?

```
<?php
if( is_array( $options ) && count( $options ) > 1)
     // generate select tag and its' option tags
else 
     // use a hidden input tag
?>
```

I would not like to use a javascript solution.

Comment: how about you hide the select tag when you generate it by counting the option

Comment: The css option would be `display: none;`, however, I would suggest going with your hidden input option.

Comment: I know about display: none; but the problem is how to "count" how many option tags are inside the select tag with css. So there will be no solution using just css. So I'll have to go for the php code about, right?